# Android Generate Signed Apk error

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I tried to generate apk from android studio for first time. I got below error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':_3dRunAdventure:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/unity3d/ads/android/BuildConfig.class
```

[image]

Please help me to upload my first android game :)

Comment: Would building  the game directly from unity be an option for you or do you need adroid studio?

Comment: @CNuts, wanna learn android studio, but now successfully built in unity3d...thx for your tips. Will google approve apk built with unity3d ?

Comment: Yes they will :)

Comment: @CNuts, wow..great to know. Got apk...Will upload now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building your game with Unity you don't need to move it to Android Studio to build the apk, you can directly build it from Unity.

All you have to do is go in **File > Build Settings** make sure you've switched the platform to android and press the build button. If you have any errors Unity will tell you what they are.

Also make sure all your scenes are added to the build

[image]

---

**For those who really want to continue with android studio and have this error:**

So an error related to this one was a bug that was fixed so I would first update Android Studio to the newest version.

The cause of this error are described in the bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81804):

> The issue is that both the multidex library and the multidex-instrumentation library both use the same package name in their manifest which in turn means that they both have BuildConfig created in the same package name which triggers a conflict when both are added.

**Note that this specific bug was in the multidex package not in the android.**

But it pretty much means that you have two of the same which causes conflict.

[This](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/export-project-from-unity-to-android-studio-and-problems-with-build-from-android-studio.388174/) is a similar question asked on the Unity Forums which contains some ways to fix the problem.